# Redirect user to cart page when add to cart button is clicked

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on WooCommerce. When the user fills the detail and clicks on add to cart button, a user does not redirect to the cart button. A notification shows at the bottom “[NAME OF THE PRODUCT] has been added to your cart, View cart.” I want that if the user clicks on add to cart button after filling details, it should be redirected to the cart page automatically.

Here is screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW2Rs.png

Comment: This might be helpful : https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-redirect-users-after-add-to-cart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Woocommerce Settings
Go to > Products, Tick Add to card behavior Redirect to the cart page

[image: Woocommerce setting screen]

Comment: thanks! It works.